# how to change models field value from views in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to set the value of is_delete field True when i click delete button from list page.

This is my views.py file

```
def delete_faculty(request, faculty_id):
    faculty = Faculty.objects.get(id=faculty_id)
    faculty.is_delete = True
    return redirect('faculty-list')
```

This is models.py

```
class Faculty(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    established = models.DateField()
    about = models.TextField()
    status_choice = (
        ('active', 'Active'),
        ('disabled', 'Disabled'),
        ('paused', 'Paused')
    )
    status = models.CharField(choices=status_choice, max_length=15)
    is_delete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This code can not set the value of True in is_delete field . How can i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# You just need to save the data

def delete_faculty(request, faculty_id):
    faculty = Faculty.objects.get(id=faculty_id)
    faculty.is_delete = True
    faculty.save()
    return redirect('faculty-list')
```